# How to fit 40x40 Excel Table into Word without going over the margins?

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have a 40x40 Excel Table that I want to paste into Word. However, I cannot do that without going over the margins and moving to the next page. It works with bitmap but data becomes unreadable. Is there any efficient way to see a big table on one page? Thanks.

Comment: After pasting you have to manually adjust columns width of WORD table.

Comment: Does (in excel) [ Select "40x40 Excel Table" > Print (selection) : Fit to One page ] produce a readable table?

Comment: @p._phidot_ It does but It is kind a produce similar result with pasting as a bitmap image. Can I at least fit the columns horizontally and rows spills over to next pages?

Comment: @Harun24HR one cell always go off :(

Comment: "produce similar result with pasting as a bitmap" means.. the content is too big for your chosen paper aspect ratio. So unless you can change the paper size.. the only next way is to split the table. | (p/s : I normally go for A3 size paper if the documentation need justifies)